# Method import using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

Help me please with method import.
I want to weave assembly and inject method call reference from base class defined in the other assembly (in fact it's the assembly where weaving code is defined).

```
private void InsertCallSetReference()
{
    //Get the load instruction to replace
    var ilProcessor = Property.SetMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();
    var argumentLoadInstructions = ilProcessor.Body.Instructions.ToList();

    MethodReference methodReference = ImportMethod("SetReference");

    foreach (var instruction in argumentLoadInstructions)
    {
        if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Stfld)
        {
            ilProcessor.InsertAfter(instruction, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Call, methodReference));
            ilProcessor.InsertAfter(instruction, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1));
            ilProcessor.InsertAfter(instruction, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, DBFieldName));
            ilProcessor.InsertAfter(instruction, ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));
            ilProcessor.Remove(instruction);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Method import code works just fine and returns method reference

```
private MethodReference ImportMethod(string name)
{
     var type = MongoConnectModule.Import(typeof(BaseDataObject));
     return MongoConnectModule.Import(type.Resolve().Methods.First(m => m.Name == name));
}
```

But after AssemblyDefinition Write call it throws me an error:

> C:\dev\MongoConnect\WeavingTaskTest\Weaving\CodeWeaving.targets(32,5):
>   error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.Void
>   MongoConnect.BaseDataObject::SetProperty(System.String,System.Object)'
>   is declared in another module and needs to be imported

```
_assemblyDefinition.Write(_assemblyPath, new WriterParameters() { WriteSymbols = true, SymbolWriterProvider = debugWriterProvider });
```

Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The reason was really funny.

`Module.Import()` method must be called from current module we want to modify, not the module where method is defined. It is not clear from original [docs](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Importing).

For example, we want to add some method defined in the `Referenced.dll` assembly to our `Main.dll` assembly. Then we have to find main module of our `Main.dll` assembly and then call `MainModule.Import(methodFromReferencedAssembly);`